# Overlapping elements in CSS

Tags: css

How can I make two elements overlap in CSS, e.g.

```
<div>Content 1</div>
<div>Content 2</div>
```

I would like the two contents (they can be anything) to overlap, so Content 2 is displayed starting at the same top left corner as Content 1 and they appear overlapped. Content 1 should begin in the normal flow of the document and not at some fixed position on the screen.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Seems like something yuou can do with positioning. Do you have any reference sites?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

the easiest way is to use `position:absolute` on both elements. You can absolutely position relative to the page, or you can absolutely position relative to a container div by setting the container div to `position:relative`

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="div1" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `position:absolute` on both elements. If one is absolutely positioned at (0,0), it will overlap the other anyway). The problem is that the dimensions of the absolute positioned element are not taken into account in the page layout.

Comment: Thank you so much, even if this answer is 4 years old, it's still useful. I bleed 'Read, Write, and CSS' every day, yet I still forget to sometimes set the parent element's position to ensure child elements don't position themselves according to the grandparents.

Comment: I was messing with this issue for hours until I came across this answer which highlighted the necessity for `position:relative` of the parent!

Answer (score 32):

Use CSS grid and set all the grid items to be in the same cell.

```css
/* for block elements */
.layered {
  display: grid;
}

.layered > * {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

/* or for inline elements */
.inline-layered {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.inline-layered > * {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

Adding the layered class to an element causes all it's children to be layered on top of each other.

if the layers are not the same size you can set the `justify-items` and `align-items` properties to set the horizontal and vertical alignment respectively.

---

#### Demo:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arye_eidelman/zm5u07pw/)

```css
.layered {
  display: grid;

  /* Set horizontal alignment of items in, case they have a different width. */
  /* justify-items: start | end | center | stretch (default); */
  justify-items: start;

  /* Set vertical alignment of items, in case they have a different height. */
  /* align-items: start | end | center | stretch (default); */
  align-items: start;
}

.layered > * {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}


/* for demonstration purposes only */
.layered > * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)
}
```

```html
<div class="layered">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100?text=first" />
  <p>
    2
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      Third layer
    </p>
    <p>
      Third layer continued
    </p>
    <p>
      Third layer continued
    </p>
    <p>
      Third layer continued
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So simple and gets the job done without worrying about "absolute" positionings. Thanks!

Comment: awesome. it definitely did the job for me. I used the "z-index: <a number>;" css property to make sure the smaller item sits on top of the bigger one. (in my case i added a little "settings" button on the top right corner of a broader area.)

Comment: this helped when I'm trying to do something within a flex box. Those "relative" and "absolute" positionings will take some extra work to fiddle with. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use relative positioning to overlap your elements. However, the space they would normally occupy will still be reserved for the element:

```
<div style="background-color:#f00;width:200px;height:100px;">
    DEFAULT POSITIONED
</div>
<div style="background-color:#0f0;width:200px;height:100px;position:relative;top:-50px;left:50px;">
    RELATIVE POSITIONED
</div>
<div style="background-color:#00f;width:200px;height:100px;">
    DEFAULT POSITIONED
</div>
```

In the example above, there will be a block of white space between the two 'DEFAULT POSITIONED' elements. This is caused, because the 'RELATIVE POSITIONED' element still has it's space reserved.

If you use absolute positioning, your elements will not have any space reserved, so your element will actually overlap, without breaking your document:

```
<div style="background-color:#f00;width:200px;height:100px;">
    DEFAULT POSITIONED
</div>
<div style="background-color:#0f0;width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;">
    ABSOLUTE POSITIONED
</div>
<div style="background-color:#00f;width:200px;height:100px;">
    DEFAULT POSITIONED
</div>
```

Finally, you can control which elements are on top of the others by using z-index:

```
<div style="z-index:10;background-color:#f00;width:200px;height:100px;">
    DEFAULT POSITIONED
</div>
<div style="z-index:5;background-color:#0f0;width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;">
    ABSOLUTE POSITIONED
</div>
<div style="z-index:0;background-color:#00f;width:200px;height:100px;">
    DEFAULT POSITIONED
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you could get away with using relative positioning and then set the top/left positioning of the second DIV until you have it in the position desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the transform: translate property by passing the appropriate values inside the parenthesis using the inspect element in Google chrome.

You have to set translate property in such way that both the `<div>` overlap each other then You can use JavaScript to show and hide both the `<div>` according to your requirements

Comment: This is actually a pretty cool way to achieve overlap effect without having to enter the domain of absolute/relative positioning which can mess up responsive design. I just needed to overlap an element by a couple of pixels and this did the job!