# CSS html dropdown moving divs down

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a html dropdown list which should be on top of other divs when selected, but it moves the below div s down and make them be there after selecting dropdown item. Code I tried is in fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RK6EF/). How can I make dropdown float on below div s on selection?

```
<div class="outer" >  
       <select id="myselect" style="width:100px;">
           <option>abc</option>
           <option>def</option>
           <option>ghi</option>
           <option>jkl</option>
          <option>abc</option>
           <option>def</option>
           <option>ghi</option>
           <option>jkl</option>

    </select>
</div>
   <div class="inner">Enter Name</div>
   <div class="inner">Enter Class</div>

</div>

 $('#myselect').on('mousedown focus', function () {
                    $('#myselect').attr('size', 11);
                    $('#myselect').css('height', '80px');
                    $('.outer').css('height', '80px');
     $('.outer').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
                });


   $('#myselect').on('change', function () {
                    $('#myselect').attr('size', '1');
                    $('#myselect').css('height', '20px');                    
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to keep the dropdown on top of the div try setting the position of the dropdown to absolute

```
$('.outer').css('position', 'absolute');
```

[JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/RK6EF/33/)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that you mentioned that in your question. I'll update the answer

Comment: Leo, This code is really great. But once I select the dropdown the bottom content is moving up. and controls next to that dropdown are merging with selected dropdown. Could you please fix this so that I can mark your answer.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you want but try this updated fiddler

Comment: Please check my http://jsfiddle.net/RK6EF/34/ to get more details. The right controls will be moving to left as position is absolute.

Comment: mate this JS Fiddler is different to the one provider in your question...sorry, I don't think anybody can help if you keep changing your question

Answer (score 1):

You should reset the height of the `.outer` as shown below:

```
            $('.outer').css('height', 'auto');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/RK6EF/8/ for fix

Comment: By 'make dropdown float on below div s on selection' do you mean to say that you want the select drop down to hide the two divs on expanding?

Comment: On selecting dropdown, I am trying to have dropdown on top of below divs.

Comment: Could you please add this as answer?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use position:absolute if you want elements to overlap
[Overlapping elements in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027657/overlapping-elements-in-css)