# How to position a SVG element under a textbox?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to do two things:

1. Make a text input take all the space in a div. My current approach is `left: 0; right: 0;` but apparently it's not working.
2. Put a SVG in a relative position to the conainer `div` in a way that I can move it just under the text inpit (I'm working on a slider component in SVG).

You can see it in [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hanbzu/M8UEv/1/)

Any clues for the positioning? `clear: both` is of no use to send the SVG to the next line? Can I achieve a relative positioning from the container `div` element somehow?

UPDATE:

I've found a workaround for my positioning question (2). To use `position: relative` on the container `div` and `position: absolute` on both child elements (an `input` and a `svg`). See the [updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hanbzu/M8UEv/6/).

Nevertheless, question (1) remains. How to make the text input fill the whole container `div`?

Comment: There is another question addressing part of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027657/overlapping-elements-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Try this to put the SVG on the next line:

```
            .container {
                width: 400px;
                height: 45px;
                background: gray;
            }

            .textfield {
                clear: both;
                float:left;
                margin-right:100px;
            }

            .slider {
                width: 200px;
                height: 15px;
                border: 1px solid #741;

            }
```

Comment: I see your idea is to add margin-right to the textfield, but I cannot afford to do that on my more general design. I've found a workaround for part 1 of my question, using absolute positioning from the container div.

Answer (score 0):

Re part #1.  Why don't you just set your input text field to be the same size as the div?

```
.textfield {
    width: 400px;
    height: 45px;
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8UEv/8/

It also has the effect of moving the SVG under the text field.

Comment: Because the size of the div is dynamically generated