# How do I add text to my image slider?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I would like to know how can I add text in my image slider.   I would like to add text to each image.  I could do it in Photoshop, but I wont to be able to edit the text in the HTML in future in case it needs changing.   How would I go about doing that?

```css
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -115%; }
45% { left: -115%; }
50% { left: -225%; }
70% { left: -225%; }
75% { left: -335%; }
95% { left: -335%; }
100% { left: -445%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 22%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}

#slider {
    max-width: 75%;    
    left: 12.5%;
    max-height: 55%;

}
```

```html
</div>
 previously -->
  <div class="container center-block">
   <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
    <figure>
     <img src="imgs/rdp.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
     <img src="imgs/wires.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
     <img src="imgs/speed.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
     <img src="imgs/tech.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    </figure>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027657/overlapping-elements-in-css

Comment: You would need to simply add the text as either `position: relative` or `position: absolute`. I can't help you any further, as you need to include **absolute URLs** for images to function correctly on external websites. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).