# d3.js how to fit multiple polygon in a div

Tags: json, d3.js, geojson

I just start learn d3.js. please bear with me. I have a drawing with a collection of polygons (maybe thousands). I like to put them as svg and colored by their attributes.

1. I'm looking at geoJson and got lost. should I use geoJson, or just simple json with array of array of points?
2. I tried mbostock's [Custom Projection](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/5663666), then my drawing does not fit in my div. also tried [Identity projection of map in d3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/djvanderlaan/5336035), but projection is incorrect, which should be 20 simple box. [image]
3. I like to attach a image file (jpg, png, ...) at then back of svg. How should I do it? should I include a boundbox in my json/geojson file so it will be easier to align?
4. I like to color each polygon use the data loaded separately, how should I do it?

here is my [test json file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkQoDfbhWXOfkx-tYZcHWhrt-wLr) in geojson format

Thanks 
Wes

Comment: What does your data look like (and is it geographic data?). As for a custom projection, why not use a pre-defined projection (if your data is geographic) or scales (if it is not)? If you already are drawing the polygons, but a custom projection makes them not scale properly, can you share what you done have to draw them?

Comment: my data basic is a floor plan of a drawing. I will attach a json right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use geojson, along with either a `geoTransform` or a `geoIdentity` projection. These are intended for planar coordinates while generally, d3.geoProjections are intended for taking points on a globe and projecting them onto a plane. This is why a custom projection may cause you some weird shapes depending on how you define it.

The `geoIdentity` option is likely the easiest: it projects planar geometry and gives you access to d3 projection methods like `.fitExtent` or `.fitSize`. For this, `fitSize` is most appropriate, it takes a geoJson object (the featureCollection) and transforms and scales the features it contains to be contained within the size specified: .`fitExtent([width,height],geoJson object)`:

```
var projection = d3.geoIdentity()   
  .fitSize([width,height],data);  // the area the features will be fitted to
```

*fitExtent can be used when desiring margins, while .fitSize assumes no margin on the left or top, see the documentation [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projection_fitExtent).*

If using a `geoIdentity` without `.fitSize` or `.fitExtent`, your coordinate values will be interpreted as pixel values. If your data aspect does not match the aspect of the svg container, then the feature will be positioned as best as possible with either excess width or height (fitSize will not distort aspect). If placing an image behind the data, ensure your image has the same aspect ratio as your svg, and occupies the same amount of pixel space.

Another issue is that a geoIdentity will result in something upside down potentially (as svg y values start at zero on the top, and increase as one goes down, which is the opposite of many other conventions).

To flip the y use `reflectY(true)` :

```
 var projection = d3.geoIdentity()
  .reflectY(true)
  .fitSize([width,height],data);
```

*Lastly, when appending, be sure to use `geoJson.features`, as otherwise you are binding a single item to your enter selection and it will be rendered as a single path. You want to bind each feature to a different element.*

Combined this gives you a properly scaled set of polygons. See [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/4b720c0df8d2e278f70bcfd87691a6e3) for everything put together (I'd use a snippet, but the json would overwhelm it).

---

While I've colored the polygons to demonstrate the extent of each polygon, you can color these in all sorts of different ways. You could have a property associated with each feature that defines a color:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"loc781","properties":{"color":"yellow"},"geometry":}...
```

and when appending the polygons:

`.attr("fill", function(d) { return d.properties.color; })`

or a value in the properties that you could use to color based on a scale:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"loc781","properties":{"value":10},"geometry":}...
```

`var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,50]).range([yellow,blue])`

and when appending the polygons:

`.attr("fill", function(d) { return scale(d.properties.value); })`

In my block example, I just used an ordinal scale and the index of the feature being appended:

`var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);`

and when appending the rectangle:

`.attr("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); });`

---

As for placing an image behind another element, that's a matter of placing things carefully in css. As noted above, just make sure that your svg bounds, your bounds for .fitSize and the bounds of the image are the same. See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027657/overlapping-elements-in-css) for a potential solution.

---

Lastly, if placing thousands of elements, it may be desirable to switch to canvas for rendering, which is rather straightforward, but a different question.